# Clothes store question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The probability to buy pants at the store is $25\%.$ (Event A) the probability to buy a blue piece of clothing is $35\%.$ (Event B) It is known that $60\%$ of the costumers are buying a piece of clothing that is not pants and is not blue. Matthew the seller is desperate to sell blue pants. The costumer have to buy something (the opposite of buying a shirt is not to buy a shirt for example)

What is the $E(x)$ of the costumers Matthew will see until he will manage to sell blue pants for the first time?

I first multiplied $0.25X0.35$ since they are not dependent events. Then I tried to calculate the E(x) thought geometric distribution formula $1/p$ when p is to but a red shirt ($0.0875$). Is this the right direction?

Comment: Are pants and piece of clothing disjoint sets?

Comment: The question is quite ambiguous. Is there a possibility to buy multiple pieces of clothing, or do we assume each customer buys either $0$ or $1$ item? Also, the number 60% seems to be useless information here. You would do well to frame the question in the form of an experiment: "Each time a customer enters the store, there is x% probability..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our calculations will be based on the following model. We have a series $\{A_n\}$ of independent purchases in the store. For each $n$ a probability $P(P)$ that $A_n$ are pants equals $0.25$, the probability $P(B)$ that $A_n$ is a blue piece of clothing is $0.35$,
and a probability $P(N)$ that $A_n$ is not pants and is not blue is $0.6$. Let $p=p_{pb}$ be a probability that $A_n$ are blue pants, $p_{pn}$ be a probability that $A_n$ pants which are not blue, $p_{nb}$ be a probability that $A_n$ is a blue piece of clothing which is not pants, and $p_{nn}$ be a probability that $A_n$ is not pants and is not blue. Then $P(P)=p_{pb}+p_{pn}$, $P(B)=p_{pb}+p_{nb}$, and $P(N)=p_{nn}$. It follows that $$1.2=0.25+0.35+0.6=P(P)+P(B)+P(N)=p_{pb}+p_{pn}+p_{pb}+p_{nb}+p_{nn}=1+p_{pb}.$$ Thus $p=p_{pb}=0.2$.
Then a probability that $A_n$ is the first purchase of blue pants is $(1-p)^{n-1}p$ and so the required expectation of the number of costumers is 
$$E=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1-p)^{n-1}p.$$

Thus $$E-(1-p)E=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1-p)^{n-1}p-(n-1)(1-p)^{n-1}p=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-p)^{n-1}p=p\frac 1{1-(1-p)}=1.$$
So $$E=\frac 1{1-(1-p)}=\frac 1p=\frac 1{0.2}=5.$$